# Delete PDF file made in R

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, delete-file

I have created a couple of pdf's using the `pdf()` device and I can't seem to delete them from my computer. I received the following error when I ran my code.

```
> pdf(file="Appendix_B_1.pdf")
> plot(1:10)
> dev.off
function (which = dev.cur()) 
{
    if (which == 1) 
        stop("cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)")
    .External(C_devoff, as.integer(which))
    dev.cur()
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000008c7ecd0>
<environment: namespace:grDevices>
```

Above is my attempt to trick the computer into thinking it is a new file.  It changed the file and I am able to open it. I just can't delete it.

I don't know what this means and all I want to do is delete the files.  Is there some workaround for either turning off the device or deleting the files from my hard drive?

Comment: +1 for reproducible example. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dev.off` is the name of a function.  When you type the name of a function, the source code for that function is printed.  If you want to run the function, add parenthesis: `dev.off()`

Comment: Wow.  I must be tired.  Thanks for the obvious solution.